# Group a list of points/tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, distance

Given a list of tuples / points I'm trying to find out how I can group each tuples that is within' a given bound (distance). It's hard to explain, but the short code should explain what I mean... I simply can't find a solution, nor how to explain the problem properly.

EG:

```
TPL = [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (7, 5), (2, 7), (6, 4), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 1)]
Print GroupTPL(TPL, distance=1)
> [
>  [(2, 7), (2, 6)], 
>  [(6, 4), (7, 5)], 
>  [(3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
> ]
```

All the things i've tried, thought up is junk.. So I see no reason to even consider sharing, hope you guys got some tips, and tricks.

Comment: Should the result lists be disjoint? I mean, a point can be at distance 1 from more then a point since "being withing x distance" is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: @Martinv.Löwis its not homework, it's for a project of mine.

Comment: Both points can be at a distance of 1. Exmple is updated.

Comment: Does only one of the two from each tuple need to be within the specified distance? I am struggling to work out why (1,1) and (2,3) are paired but (1,1) and (2,7) are not.

Comment: How does `(2,2)` get in your output at all?  there's no `(2,2)` in `TPL`...

Comment: Haha, my mistake. Will be removed.

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand what you want.  how is `[(2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]` a group?  The distance between `(2,3)` and `(3,1)` is greater than 1 ...

Comment: ... same with `(6,4)` and `(7,5)`

Comment: Your output does not make sense. Could you explain your problem ? I thought I understood your problem, but your output is inconsistent with your statements

Comment: I think OP means [Chebychev's distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) when he says `distance`.

Comment: @mgilson This seems to be solved by musically_ut. Chebychev's distance seems to be correct from what I read.

Comment: However, do note that `(2,1)` and `(3,1)` would then belong in the same group in that case (as is the case in my solution).

Comment: Ofcourse, its my example that is somewhat bad. @mgilson: bacause (3, 2) is in the same group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you intend [Chebyshev distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) when you wanted to cluster the points together.

In this case, the most straight forward way to do it would be by using a [Union Find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Here is a implementation I have used:

```python
class UnionFind:
    """Union-find data structure. Items must be hashable."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Create a new empty union-find structure."""
        self.weights = {}
        self.parents = {}

    def __getitem__(self, obj):
        """X[item] will return the token object of the set which contains `item`"""

        # check for previously unknown object
        if obj not in self.parents:
            self.parents[obj] = obj 
            self.weights[obj] = 1
            return obj 

        # find path of objects leading to the root
        path = [obj]
        root = self.parents[obj]
        while root != path[-1]:
            path.append(root)
            root = self.parents[root]

        # compress the path and return
        for ancestor in path:
            self.parents[ancestor] = root
        return root

    def union(self, obj1, obj2):
        """Merges sets containing obj1 and obj2."""
        roots = [self[obj1], self[obj2]]
        heavier = max([(self.weights[r],r) for r in roots])[1]
        for r in roots:
            if r != heavier:
                self.weights[heavier] += self.weights[r]
                self.parents[r] = heavier
```

Then writing the function `groupTPL` is easy:

```python
def groupTPL(TPL, distance=1):
    U = UnionFind()

    for (i, x) in enumerate(TPL):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(TPL)):
            y = TPL[j]
            if max(abs(x[0] - y[0]), abs(x[1] - y[1])) <= distance:
                U.union(x, y)

    disjSets = {}
    for x in TPL:
        s = disjSets.get(U[x], set())
        s.add(x)
        disjSets[U[x]] = s

    return [list(x) for x in disjSets.values()]
```

Running it on your set produces:

```python
>>> groupTPL([(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (7, 5), (2, 7), (6, 4), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 1)])
[
 [(2, 7), (2, 6)], 
 [(6, 4), (7, 5)], 
 [(3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
]
```

However, this implementation, though simple, is still `O(n^2)`. If the number of points grows very large, an efficient implementation would use [k-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Answer (score 1):

my answer is late; but this is short and working!!

```
from itertools import combinations

def groupTPL(inputlist):  
    ptdiff = lambda (p1,p2):(p1,p2,abs(p1[0]-p2[0])+ abs(p1[1]-p2[1]),sqrt((p2[1] - p1[1])**2 + (p2[0] - p1[0])**2 ))
    diffs=[ x for x in map(ptdiff, combinations(inputlist,2)) if x[2]==1 or x[3]==sqrt(2)]
    nk1=[]
    for x in diffs:
        if len(nk1)>0:
            for y in nk1:
                if x[0] in y or x[1] in y:
                    y.add(x[0])
                    y.add(x[1])
                else:
                    if set(x[0:2]) not in nk1:
                        nk1.append(set(x[0:2]))
        else:
            nk1.append(set(x[0:2]))
    return [list(x) for x in nk1]

print groupTPL([(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (7, 5), (2, 7), (6, 4), (2, 3), (2, 6), (3, 1)])
```

this will give output as::::

```
[[(3, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(6, 4), (7, 5)], [(2, 7), (2, 6)]]
```

Comment: Only spotted this now, but this one (as is), does not take a distance parameter tho, currently just a regular connected components test. Cool none the less :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to fill in an alternative, which is not by default faster than the Union-Find code given by `musically-ut`, but it's is simple to use with `Cython` and thereby achieving 3x speedup, yet there are cases where it's faster by default. It's not my work, it's something that was found here: https://github.com/MerlijnWajer/Simba/blob/master/Units/MMLCore/tpa.pas

*Cython-code:* (remove cdef int..., and int w, int h to use with Python)

```
def group_pts(pts, int w, int h):
  cdef int t1, t2, c, ec, tc, l

  l = len(pts)-1
  if (l < 0): return False
  result = [list() for i in range(l+1)]
  c = 0
  ec = 0
  while ((l - ec) >= 0):
    result[c].append(pts[0])
    pts[0] = pts[l - ec]
    ec += 1
    tc = 1
    t1 = 0
    while (t1 < tc):
      t2 = 0
      while (t2 <= (l - ec)):
        if (abs(result[c][t1][0] - pts[t2][0]) <= w) and \
           (abs(result[c][t1][1] - pts[t2][1]) <= h):

          result[c].append(pts[t2])
          pts[t2] = pts[l - ec]
          ec += 1
          tc += 1
          t2 -= 1
        t2 += 1
      t1 += 1
    c += 1

  return result[0:c]
```

This can probably be optimized a bit, but I've not take the time to do so. This also allows for duplicates, which Union-Find structure is not very happy about.

It could be interesting to use SciPy's kd-tree to handle this, that would without a doubt bring the speed up for larger datasets.